# issue with forms in bootstrap and html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bit of a problem and i need some help. I am learning new things and trying to get some skills with the time spend on learning.

I want to make this picture and forms look the same as the picture. I am posting my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYzsH.png)

index.html

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="row">

   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/lqvopodravnenasnimka.jpg" alt="smiley face">
    </div>  <!--col-md-5-->


    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <h3>Send Request</h3>
        <p id="mainparagraph">Заповядайте в нашия нов хотел Grand Hotel Gergana. Ние Ви предлагаме отлични условия, където можете да прекарате своите ценни свободни дни.</p>
        <form name="myForm" action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group form-group-sm" style="margin-top:20px;">
                        <label for="firstname" class="control-label">Name</label> <!--name-->
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" style="width:100%;" name="fname">
                    </div><!-- form-group-->
                </div><!--col-md-5-->

                 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group form-group-sm" style="margin-top:20px;">
                        <label for="surname" class="control-label">Surname</label>  <!--surname -->
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" style="width:100%;" name="sname">
                    </div><!-- form-group-->
                </div><!--col-md-5--> 
            </div><!--row-->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group form-group-sm" style="margin-top:20px;">
                        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" style="width:100%;" name="mail">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--row-->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group form-group-sm" style="margin-top:20px;">
                        <label for="phone" class="control-label">Mobile phone</label>
                        <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"><p style="color:gray; font-style:italic; font-size:0.7em;">Sample: +352XXXXXXXXX</p> -->
                        <br>
                        <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" style="width:100%;" name="mphone">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--row-->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group form-group-sm" style="margin-top:20px;">
                        <label for="date" class="control-label">Date of birth</label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number" Placeholder="DD" style="width:55px;" name="day">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number" Placeholder="MM" style="width:55px;" name="month">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number" Placeholder="YYYY" style="width:90px;" name="year">
                    </div>
                </div><!--col-md-6-->

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group form-group-sm" >
                        <label for="text" class="control-label" style="margin-top:20px;">Nationality</label>
                        <br>
                        <select class="options" name="cars" style="width:100%;">
                            <option value="България">България</option>
                            <option value="Румъния">Румъния</option>
                            <option value="Гърция">Гърция</option>
                            <option value="Сърбия">Сърбия</option>
                        </select>

                    </div><!--form-group-->
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="submit" value="SAMPLE BUTTON">
                </div>
            </div><!--row-->



        </form>
    </div><!--col-md-7-->
```

Comment: what's the issue

Comment: i posted the picture with my result. I have a problem with the width of the input forms

Answer (score 0):

Its quite a simple fix. You were really close! Firstly with Bootstrap you need to have a container, so that's a class that would be on your main div that holds everything so for this instance it would be your jumbotron div.

```
<div class="jumbotron container">
```

This will format 90% of what you are trying to achieve into a neat box where all the cols work in harmony with each other.

As for the input boxes, I see you were having difficulty with your date inputs. This too is an easy fix. Simply add the following code to your css:

```
#number {
   float: left;
}
```

This will push them close together as seen in your picture.

Working example here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MoqRMK

I am sure you are experienced enough to make any other required changes.